# While loop computed hash compare in bash?

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a script to count the number of zero fill sectors for a dd image file. This is what I have so far, but it is throwing an error saying it cannot open file #hashvalue#. Is there a better way to do this or what am I missing? Thanks in advance.

```
count=1
zfcount=0
while read Stuff; do
count+=1
if [ $Stuff == "bf619eac0cdf3f68d496ea9344137e8b" ]; then
zfcount+=1
fi
echo $Stuff
done < "$(dd if=test.dd bs=512 2> /dev/null | md5sum | cut -d ' ' -f 1)"
echo "Total Sector Count Is: $count"
echo "Zero Fill Sector Count is: $zfcount"
```

Comment: execute just `$(dd if=test.dd bs=512 2> /dev/null | md5sum | cut -d ' ' -f 1)`. That value will be used as a **filename** in you `while ..; done < file` structure. Is that what you intend? Maybe you want `done <($(dd if=test.dd bs=512 2> /dev/null | md5sum | cut -d ' ' -f 1))` . ( by which I mean `process substition`. not certain I've got this exactly right on the syntax with `<` chars). Good luck.

Comment: You either need a 'here string' with [`<<<`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings) or [command substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution).  I would expect the pipeline to produce a single value, though.  You'll need to think again about what you're up to.

Comment: shellter, I would just want the resulting string compared to the static string and if they match, increment zfcount. I don't want that string to act as a file name. I want to scan all sectors (or 512 bytes at a time) for the full file.

Jonathan, are you referring to my "done <" line?

Thank you both for responses.

Comment: I agree with JL. I think `<<<` here-strings should work for you. Just add 2 more `<` chars ;-). Also, for your own certainty, either add `echo $Stuff` at the top of the loop or turn on shell debug/trace with `set -vx` (and turn it off as needed with `set +vx`).  Good luck.

Comment: This line:
done <<< "$(dd if=test.dd bs=512 2> /dev/null | md5sum | cut -d ' ' -f 1)"

Gives me this error now:
Syntax error: redirection unexpected

Comment: Are you sure you're using `bash`? `<<<` is a `bash`ism, and the rest of your code looks like standard POSIX shell.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this in bash is going to be extremely slow -- on the order of 20 minutes for a 1GB file.

Use another language, like Python, which can do this in a few seconds (if storage can keep up):

```
python -c '
import sys
total=0
zero=0
file = open(sys.argv[1], "r")
while True:
  a=file.read(512)
  if a:
    total = total + 1
    if all(x == "\x00" for x in a):
      zero = zero + 1
  else:
    break
print "Total sectors: " + str(total)
print "Zeroed sectors: " + str(zero)
' yourfilehere
```

Comment: Thanks, that code is pretty solid. My python is almost non existent. Only comment I have is your total sector count is off (matches zero count), but that was more of a additional info thing.

Comment: This happens when the file is all zeroes. If you e.g. generate a file with `( head -c $((512*42)); head -c $((512*58)) | tr '\0' a; ) < /dev/zero  > file`, you'll see "Total sectors: 100. Zeroed sectors: 42" as expected.

Comment: Ah, I see. I messed up when I created my image. Thanks! That is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Your error message comes from this line:

```
done < "$(dd if=test.dd bs=512 2> /dev/null | md5sum | cut -d ' ' -f 1)"
```

What that does is reads your entire `test.dd`, calculates the `md5sum` of that data, and parses out just the hash value, then, by merit of being included inside `$( ... )`, it substitutes that hash value in place, so you end up with that line essentially acting like this:

```
done < e6e8c42ec6d41563fc28e50080b73025
```

(except, of course, you have a different hash). So, your shell attempts to read from a file named like the hash of your `test.dd` image, can't find the file, and complains.

Also, it appears that you are under the assumption that `dd if=test.dd bs=512 ...` will feed you 512-byte blocks one at a time to iterate over. This is not the case. `dd` will read the file in `bs`-sized blocks, and write it in the same sized blocks, but it does not insert a separator or synchronize in any way with whatever is on the other side of its pipe line.